# Share DbContext among threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

We use the pattern 'one dbconnection by request' on our asp.net mvc applications (C# / VS 2k15).
Basically we create a DbContext on BeginRequest and Dispose() it on EndRequest.

I used to save this DbContext on HttpContext but we ran into a little more complex scenario where we needed run multiple threads and this solution stopped working since HttpContext is not shared among threads.

First I thought using CallContext but its objects should be Serializable, which isn't the case of DbContext.

The (not optional) solution I thought of was save the DbContexts on a public static Dictionary where the key (long) is the thread id, but I think there's a better solution.

What's the best solution to share DbContext among threads?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to run multiple threads in ASP.NET? That's the far more important question.

Comment: What's the measurable performance drain for just creating/using/disposing a single DB Context only where it's used?  Do you really need the additional complexity and additional problems of trying to synchronize all of this?

Comment: @mason actually isn't thread but Task - the result is the same - I have a particular need on an Api call

Comment: @David We have our own architecture which works using this pattern - many classes integrate reusing the DbContext opened when the request was made - anyway, changing this would required lots of refactoring, which we'd like to avoid

Comment: You're just digging yourself into a deeper hole by avoiding refactoring.

Comment: @JeovaAlmeida If you're performing lots of asynchronous IO operations then you're *only ever running code on the request's thread*, and so there's no problem keeping the context on the httpcontext and using it in all of those asynchronous operations.

Comment: @JeovaAlmeida: *"actually isn't thread but Task"* - If it's not a separate thread then what's the issue?  The core of the problem description is that you're trying to share a DB Context between threads (which is a very, very bad idea).  But if that's not what you're trying to do, then what's the problem?  What is the exact error/issue you encounter and what is the code which produces that error/issue?

Comment: Servy and @David When the context switch from the request one to the [Task's](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2), the HttpContext.Current, which was valid on the first, is null on the second. So, I need to change the way I save my DbContexts for reuse so that the classes from our architecture which relies there's an existing and opened DbContext doesn't crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the best solution to share DbContext among threads?

To not do that.  A DbContext instance cannot be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

Just have your background processes create a new DbContext in a `using` block.  The underlying database connections are pooled and will be reused.

If you just want to pass a DbContext instance across the Tasks that flow from a single http request, and can guarantee that it will not be accessed by two concurrent Tasks or Threads, then you can use [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

You can also [capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) a local variable referring to the DbContext and explicitly pass it to a task you await.  EG

```
await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    var e = db.MyEntity.First();
    //. . . 
   });
```

Comment: We have our own architecture which works using this pattern - many classes integrate reusing the DbContext opened when the request was made and we'd like to keep it as is - The DbContext won't be accessed by multiple threads or Tasks, we simply need it to be created on BeginRequest and on the context of the Task be accessed. We already have a Dictionary to save instances of DbContext by thread but it's currently saved on HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest against doing that.

But if you insist on it and you're using Inversion of Control library than it's quite likely that it will support [Per thread lifestyle](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#perthread)